# How to make a dictation grammar which accepts medical terms?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, speech-recognition, sapi

I am using sapi 5.4 and my grammar file contains

```
 <RULE ID="VID_InputType">
     <L PROPID="VID_InputType">
       <DICTATION MAX="INF"/>
     </L>
 </RULE>
```

But also I know that dictation will contain only medical terms is there a way to specify that in grammar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify the dictation topic in the grammar; you do it in code.

But to do that, you need a medical dictation grammar.  [Trigram Technology](http://www.trigramtech.com/DictationTopics.html) sells one, but it's expensive.  Once you purchase and install it, the documentation will describe the dictation topic.

Once you have that, the code is pretty simple:

```
ISpRecoGrammar pGrammar; // assumes already created
HRESULT hr = _cpGrammar->LoadDictation( topic, SPLO_STATIC ); // topic defined by Trigram
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = _cpGrammar->SetDictationState(SPRS_ACTIVE);
}
```